# Nameref is broken after renewing sections command

Tags: sectioning, nameref, scrartcl

To comply with the rules of my university I have to *not* print section headings and make some other changes to TOCs and sections. Here is a (more or less minimal) MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, headsepline, toc=sectionentrywithdots, listof=entryprefix, parskip=half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\providecaptionname{english}{\listofatocentryname}{App.}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AfterTOCHead[atoc]{\let\if@dynlist\if@tocleft}
\newcommand*{\useappendixtocs}{
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}
  \RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=0pt]{section, subsection, subsubsection}
  \RedeclareSectionCommands[tocnumwidth=85pt]{section, subsection, subsubsection}
  \addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries}
  \renewcommand*\listoflofentryname{\mdseries}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
  \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
  }
\newcommand*{\usestandardtocs}{
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\PrefixBy{App.},
  listname={Appendix}%
]{atoc}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \useappendixtocs
  \listofatocs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \clearmainofpairofpagestyles
  \clearplainofpairofpagestyles
  \rohead{\textnormal{App.~\arabic{section}}}
  \lohead{\textnormal{\currentname}}
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test1}
This is a reference to appendix \ref{sec:app2} with the name \nameref{sec:app2}.
At this point, reference is made to Annex 2.
The number is correct, but nameref outputs the wrong name.

\clearpage
\appendix
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
\par\refstepcounter{section}
\sectionmark{#1}
\addcontentsline{atoc}{section}{\bfseries\protect\numberline{\thesection}{\mdseries#1}}
\lohead{\textnormal{#1}}
}

\section{First Appendix}
\label{sec:app1}
Appendix 1

\clearpage

\section{Second Appendix}
\label{sec:app2}
Appendix 2

\end{document}
```

As you can see, because of the renewal of the section command in the appendix, `nameref` does not work anymore:
[image: wrong nameref output]

How can I either fix the `nameref` issue or achieve my goal, which is appendices looking like this:
[image: an appendix as it should be]

in a way, that does not break nameref?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the title:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{Test1}
This is a reference to appendix \ref{sec:app2} with the name \nameref{sec:app2}.
At this point, reference is made to Annex 2.
The number is correct, but nameref outputs the wrong name.

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
\par\refstepcounter{section}%
\sectionmark{#1}%
\NR@gettitle{#1}%<---------
\addcontentsline{atoc}{section}{\bfseries\protect\numberline{\thesection}{\mdseries#1}}%
\lohead{\textnormal{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
\section{Second Appendix}
\label{sec:app2}
Appendix 2

\end{document}
```

[image]